# passing httpservletrequest to method

Tags: java

I am having a servlet class which takes the HttpServletRequest, i need to pass the request to another method. How can i get the request in another method.

Servlet:

```
     public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
                               final HttpServletResponse response)
      XmlParser xmlParser = new XmlParser();
      xmlParser.getRequest(request);
```

XmlParser class:

```
public class XmlParser{
    public void getRequest () //How can i get the request parameter from the servlet. 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: ...Take it in as a constructor parameter?  I'm not quite certain how this question is specific to `HttpServletRequest`.  This would be applicable for any object.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 2):

Pass it to the constructor:

```
public class XmlParser{
    final private HttpServletRequest request;
    public XmlParser(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }
    // use it in othe methods...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class XmlParser {
    private final HttpServletRequest request = null;

    public XmlParser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    ... other methods
```

Answer (score 0):

Store reference to request in your XmlParser class. And use it in `XmlParser` methods when you need to get a parameter from this request.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XmlParser{
HttpServletRequest request;
public XmlParser(HttpServletRequest request){
this.request=request;
}
public void getRequest () 
{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are valid, but I would recommend you not to couple the XmlParser with HttpServletRequest. Retrieve all data you need from HttpServletRequest (an InputStream, which reads the body contents?) and pass it to the XmlParser.